# AdMob adaptive banner is not showing in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, android-jetpack-compose

I have an AdMob regular banner and an adaptive banner on a composable. The regular banner is showing alright, but the adaptive banner is not. Can anyone please help resolve this?

[AdMob Reference](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/anchored-adaptive#sample_code)

```
@Composable
fun AdNetworkApp() {
    val deviceCurrentWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp.toInt()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text("Adaptive Banner")

        // shows an Adaptive banner test ad
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                AdView(context).apply {
                    adSize = AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
                        context,
                        deviceCurrentWidth
                    )
                    adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.ad_id_adaptive_banner)
                    loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            }
        )

        Text("Regular Banner")

        // shows a banner test ad
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                AdView(context).apply {
                    adSize = AdSize.BANNER
                    adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.ad_id_banner)
                    loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            }
        )
        ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think JC yet supports ads. Why not implement a `AndroidView` itself?

Comment: Jetpack Compose is showing ads alright using Android View. As I said, one ad is being shown, but another one is not. The adaptive ad has some issues with the settings probably.

Comment: @RawHasan this is what I see when running your code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVblv.png. Is it expected result?

Comment: @Philip Dukhov Yes! The adaptive banner is showing first (although the size is not right). Have you fixed anything? I don't see the first one on the emulator. Just the later one shows.

Comment: @RawHasan the only thing I changed was `adUnitId` I'm using same for both views. Check out if your ids are valid

Comment: @Philip Dukhov That is working now, thanks! Looks like the issue is with the test ID they've provided. If I use the test ID for the regular banner to show the adaptive banner, it works fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to check when your banner is not showing is `adUnitId`.

Also it can be not shown if the width passed to `adSize` is too big. But in your case, your `padding` applied to `Column` stops it from showing full width.

I suggest you not using unknown constants like `40`. When you're sure that current view is top one, you can calculate width inside column like `screenWidthDp - 2 * padding`

The most "accurate" is to get width of column with `onSizeChanged`.

I've made a sample to test `AdView` with different widths, and none seems working good. But I suggest you check out on a real `adUnitId` instead of the test one, maybe there situation is better.

```
val deviceCurrentWidth = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val padding = 16
var i by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
var containerWidth by remember { mutableStateOf<Int?>(null) }
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,

    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(padding.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .onSizeChanged {
            containerWidth = it.width
        }
) {
    val items =
        listOf(
            "deviceCurrentWidth - 40" to deviceCurrentWidth - 40,
            "deviceCurrentWidth - padding * 2" to deviceCurrentWidth - padding * 2,
            "AdSize.FULL_WIDTH" to AdSize.FULL_WIDTH,
            "onSizeChanged" to with(LocalDensity.current) {
                containerWidth?.let { containerWidth ->
                    (containerWidth / density).roundToInt()
                }
            }
        )
    items.forEach {
        val (title, width) = it
        if (width == null) {
            return@forEach
        }

        Text(title)
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                AdView(context).apply {
                    adSize = AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
                        context,
                        width
                    )
                    adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
                    loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            },
            update = { adView ->
                adView.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                i // needed to update view on i change
            },
        )
    }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            i++
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

p.s. Also a little tip: use a modifier as the last argument: in this case you do not need to use a comma, so it becomes much easier to add and delete lines

```
Column(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
)
```

Comment: Thanks! The modifier tip is super useful. Very annoying writing a comma first to change the modifiers if placed in the middle.

Comment: @RawHasan I suggest you removing your next question if this one solved your width problem. You're getting a correct value with `screenWidthDp`

Comment: Thanks! But the issue is not solved. I am trying to deduct 40 from the device width like this `val deviceCurrentWidth = (deviceCurrentWidthDp / deviceCurrentDp).minus(40)`, as you say it is not showing because of the overwidth, which is giving me an error: `Invalid width for AdSize: -40`

Comment: I need to show it as screen width - column padding

Comment: @RawHasan what is this division? Why not just `deviceCurrentWidth - 40`?

Comment: Got it finally. `deviceCurrentWidthDp.toInt() - 40` worked. Thanks! Removing the other question.

Comment: Sorry can't delete that one anymore. People already posted answers.

Comment: @RawHasan see my updated answer, you can use `AdSize.FULL_WIDTH`. Also please comment second question under my comment, that you're agree with me, so guy who review it will close your question.

Comment: Getting this warning for FULL_WIDTH: 'AdSize' is deprecated. Deprecated in Java

Comment: @RawHasan not sure what's causing this warning, [FULL_WIDTH](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize#public-static-final-int-full_width) doesn't seems to be deprecated

Comment: It says the whole AdSize library is deprecated. FULL_WIDTH also showing some unexpected behavior. It is showing smaller ads, keeping empty space on the sides.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! It looks like lots of work!! :) Can you please answer one last question regarding this: If I use `LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp - padding * 2` as the ad size, is there any reason for it to not look good on every device?

Comment: @RawHasan no, it should be fine. Unless you have an other padding in the view which contains current view

Comment: Thanks! I'll stick with it then for the time being.