# How to get device width in integer to show an AdMob adaptive banner in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to get the device width of the current orientation to display an AdMob adaptive banner. I tried to get it like this:

```
val deviceCurrentWidthDp = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
val deviceCurrentDp = LocalConfiguration.current.densityDpi
val deviceCurrentWidth = deviceCurrentWidthDp / deviceCurrentDp
```

And passed it to display the banner which does not show the banner:

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        AdView(context).apply {
            adSize = AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
                context,
                deviceCurrentWidth // works if replaced with 300
            )
            adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.ad_id_banner)
            loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
        }
    }
)
```

If I replace `deviceCurrentWidth` with a fixed value of `300`, the banner shows alright. How can I fix this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've marked this question as need to be closed. This question is a logical continuation of the [previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69029609/3585796), and the problem was that the container padding was not included in the calculation. I believe this not gonna help anyone else, because `screenWidthDp` returns correct device width.

Comment: No problem with closing, thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it. Using `deviceCurrentWidthDp.toInt() - 40` finally worked.

Comment: Well that's more of a workaround. Every device does not have the same width so the subtracted value will not always result in the same output

Comment: Since the calculation is originating from `dp`, should it not keep the same border for the ad?

Answer (score 1):

Using this method you can check it is tablet or mobile and you can get inches in integer datatype

```
fun checkTablet(activity: Activity): Boolean {
    val metrics = activity.resources.displayMetrics
    val widthInches = metrics.widthPixels / metrics.xdpi
    val heightInches = metrics.heightPixels / metrics.ydpi
    val diagonalInches = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(widthInches.toDouble(), 2.0) + Math.pow(
            heightInches.toDouble(),
            2.0
        )
    )
    return diagonalInches > 6.5
}
```